# Making the color of a button change after a certain period of time on HTML

Tags: html

I have a button, and I would need it to change its color after a certain period of time. Then after it is pressed it should reset and go back to green. Then again after time it should change color again. How do I do this? I would like it to first change from Green to Yellow, then from Yellow to Red. I cannot seem to find such information to do this and my HTML skills are very poor.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code for the button currently:

```
<input class="centered" type="button" onclick='''||'$("#bcTarget").barcode("'||SHOP_ORDER_OPERATION_API.GET_OP_ID(e.order_no,e.release_no,e.sequence_no,e.op_no)||'", "code128",{barWidth:2, barHeight:30});''' ||' value="Tarkastus" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

basic `input`

```
<input id="btnTest" type="button" value="click"/>
```

Javascript code;

```
var col = "default"; //keep the color string
setInterval(function() {
  if (col == "default") { 
    $("#btnTest").css("background-color", "green");
    col = "green";
  } else if (col == "green") {
    $("#btnTest").css("background-color", "yellow");
    col = "yellow";
  } else if (col == "yellow") {
    $("#btnTest").css("background-color", "red");
    col = "red";
  }
}, 2000); // 2 second interval
$("#btnTest").on("click", function() { // on click change color to green
  $("#btnTest").css("background-color", "green");
})
```

here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3oyr61yr/9/)

Hope helps,

Comment: This works! Thank you. How would I be able to loop this? I would like it to go back to yellow and red after I click it?

Comment: This is just for logic. The interval event, click event and showed how to change background color. You should implement the rest. @Moks99

Comment: If it worked please upvote and mark solution as the answer please @Moks99

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/20xj8skn/1/

```js
changeColor = function(color) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("submit").style.background = color;
    document.getElementById("submit").style.color = "#000";
  }, 2000);
}

clicked = function() {
  changeColor('red');
}

changeColor('yellow');
```

```css
#submit {
  background: rgb(0,255,0);
  color: '#fff';
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="clicked();"/>
```

I guess this is what you are looking for.